# How do I populate sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, csv

Can anyone suggest the best way to do the following please?

I have a UIViewController with 3 buttons on it. For clarity, the buttons are:
1. Hotels
2. Shopping
3. Indoor Activities

On a button click, it will go to a UITableView that will have a list of businesses associated with that button.
So clicking on Hotels, will show a list of hotels.

But my issue is as follows.

For Hotels and Shopping, the UITableView will need to have sections to destinguish e.g. 3 Star hotels from 4 Star hotels.
And for shopping there will have to be at least 12 different sections in the UITableView.
Indoor Activities will have no sections - only a list of businesses.

To populate the UITableView, I read the list of all businesses from a .csv file.
In my .csv file I have given each group of businesses a ID e.g. hotels (both 3 and 4 star) are ID 1, shopping (all 12 different section) are ID 2 and Indoor Activities are ID 3
Here is a sample of what the .csv file looks like.

```
ID, Company Name, Address, Tel, Email, Website, Details, Image Name
```

I have managed to read the list of businesses in a group but I am having trouble putting Hotels and Shopping into sections.
I have tried the following. For e.g. the Hotels I add 2 arrays and then check the names of each hotel. If a hotel name is e.g. 1A or 2A, I add it to the 3 star array, and if its e.g. 1B or 2B I add it to the 4 star array.
But this is very tedious and not best practice I would imagine. 
And it will become even more tedious as the shopping section contains dozens of businesses. So I cant check each business name seperately.
Here is how I add Business Objects to an NSMutableArray _array to define sections. 
But like I mentioned, with all the business names to check, this will become very tedious.

```
- (NSArray *) csvArray2PresidentsArray:(NSArray *)csvArray
{
    int i = 0;

    for (NSArray *row in csvArray)
    {
        // The first row is a header - SKIP
        if (i > 0)
        {
            BusinessDetailContent *_businessDetailContent = [[BusinessDetailContent alloc] init];
            _businessDetailContent.no           = [row objectAtIndex:0];
            _businessDetailContent.companyName  = [row objectAtIndex:1];
            _businessDetailContent.address      = [row objectAtIndex:2];
            _businessDetailContent.tel          = [row objectAtIndex:3];
            _businessDetailContent.email        = [row objectAtIndex:4];
            _businessDetailContent.website      = [row objectAtIndex:5];
            _businessDetailContent.details      = [row objectAtIndex:6];      
            _businessDetailContent.imageName    = [row objectAtIndex:7];

            // USE TO FILTER RESULTS
            NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.tagNumber];

            if ([_businessDetailContent.no isEqualToString:@"1A"] || 
            [_businessDetailContent.no isEqualToString:@"2A"])

            {
                [_threeStarArray addObject: _businessDetailContent];
            }

    else if ([_businessDetailContent.no isEqualToString:@"1B"] || 
                 [_businessDetailContent.no isEqualToString:@"2B"])

            {
        [_fourStarArray addObject: _businessDetailContent];
            }  
        }
        i++;
    }

    [_array addObject: _threeStarArray];
[_array addObject: _fourStarArray];

    return (NSArray *) self.filteredArray;
}
```

Is there a better way to check/handle this? I had thought about adding another field to the .csv file that will define a e.g. hotel as being 3 or 4 Star. And the same for all the businesses.
Then in the above code I can just scan for this secondary ID and depending what it is, I add it to its own array/section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I'd be more inclined to us an NSMutableDictionary and stick the values in there:

```
[aDict setValue:threeStarArray forKey:@"three_star"];
```

etc... you can then grab the data specifically and it's more tidy rather than sticking all the items into 1 array. You can then distinguish sections in the tableview by the Key Value.

Also you don't need to cast `NSArray` when you return (assuming `self.filteredArray` is an `NSArray`).